# Melhoria de código

Tags: r, dplyr

Boa tarde. Tenho a seguinte estrutura de dados:

```
structure(list(CIDADE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), MES = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), CLIENTES = c(29L, 26L, 25L, 29L, 
30L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
25L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 30L, 30L, 29L), REMANEJADOS = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L), REMANEJAMENTOS = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), TRANSFERENCIAS = c(2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L), 
EVASOES = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L), HORAS = c(80, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80), TURMAS = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("CIDADE", "MES", "CLIENTES", 
"REMANEJADOS", "REMANEJAMENTOS", "TRANSFERENCIAS", "EVASOES", 
"HORAS", "TURMAS"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Calculei o acumulado de algumas variáveis que são necessárias

```
dados <- dados %>% 
  group_by(CIDADE) %>% 
  mutate(CliAcu = cumsum(CLIENTES),
         RmdAcu = cumsum(REMANEJADOS),
         RmtAcu = cumsum(REMANEJAMENTOS),
         TrsAcu = cumsum(TRANSFERENCIAS),
         EvsAcu = cumsum(EVASOES),
         TurAcu = cumsum(TURMAS))
```

Agora preciso calcular uma fórmula que leva em conta essas variáveis acumuladas (`CliAcu`, `RmdAcu`, `RmtAcu`, `TrsAcu`, `EvsAcu`, `TurAcu`) e a variável `HORAS` de acordo com a seguinte relação:

```
Formula = (CliAcu + RmdAcu - RmtAcu[mês_anterior] - TrsAcu[mês_anterior] - EvsAcu[mês_anterior])*HORAS/TurAcu
```

Tenho o seguinte código que faz o que eu necessito:

```
if(dim(dados)[1] != 0){
  dados$Valor[1] <- (dados$CliAcu[1]+dados$RmdAcu[1]-0-0-0)*
                         dados$HORAS[1]/dados$TurAcu[1]
  if(nrow(dados) != 1){
    for(i in 2:nrow(dados)){
      if(dados$MES[i] == 1){
        dados$Valor[i] <- (dados$CliAcu[i]+dados$RmdAcu[i]-0-0-0)*
                               dados$HORAS[i]/dados$TurAcu[i]
      } else{
        if(dados$MES[i] <= dados$MES[i-1]){
          dados$Valor[i] <- (dados$CliAcu[i]+dados$RmdAcu[i]-0-0-0)*
                                 dados$HORAS[i]/dados$TurAcu[i]
        } else{
          dados$Valor[i] <- (dados$CliAcu[i]+dados$RmdAcu[i]-
                               dados$EvsAcu[i-1]-dados$RmtAcu[i-1]-
                               dados$TrsAcu[i-1])*
                                 dados$HORAS[i]/dados$TurAcu[i]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Como observação, eu estou diminuindo 0 três vezes em 3 contas pois no 1º mês das observações as subtrações não me interessam (esse 1º mês pode ser qualquer um dos meses do ano).

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para melhoria desse último código, utilizando o pacote `dplyr` por exemplo.

Comment: Vc precisa calcular o valor da formula por cidade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para lidar com valores "a frente" ou "atrás" de uma observação, dado a ordenação de uma outra variável, o `dplyr` tem as funções `arrange` para ordenar, e `lag` e `lead` para acessar o valor anterior ou posterior de uma linha no `data.frame`/`tibble`. Existe a opção de achar pegar o valor x anterior, mas para isso cheque a documentação [aqui](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.2/topics/lead-lag).
Existe também uma [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) só sobre o assunto de window functions bem legal.

No seu caso, eu acho possível que seu problema seja resolvido com o seguinte código:

```
dados %>%
    group_by(CIDADE) %>% 
    arrange(MES) %>% 
    transmute(
        MES,
        calculo = (CliAcu + RmdAcu - lag(RmtAcu, default = 0) - lag(TrsAcu, default = 0) - lag(EvsAcu, default = 0))*HORAS/TurAcu
        )
```

Assumindo que queira o valor por cidade. O resultado da computação anterior é:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 3
# Groups:   CIDADE [2]
    CIDADE   MES   calculo
    <fctr> <int>     <dbl>
1      A     1        NA
2      B     1        NA
3      A     2  760.0000
4      B     2  976.0000
5      A     3  810.0000
6      B     3 1146.6667
7      A     4  968.8889
8      B     4  952.0000
9      A     5  966.6667
10     B     5 1054.5455
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Comment: Era isso que eu precisava. Só fiz umas correções em uns itens que você digitou errado no código e incluí o `default = 0` na função `lag`. Valeu mesmo